# Using Bash Script and mosquitto_sub what code would be used to execute a script based on MQTT message true or false?

Tags: bash, loops, mqtt

I need to execute a shell script when an MQTT message of '1' arrives,  how can I do this with a bash script?

I think it would have something to do with while listen do ; else but I don't know the syntax that should be used.

So far all I have is the subscription.

```
#!/bin/bash
mosquitto_sub -t "1999-Connect"
```

Per suggestion below

```
#!/bin/bash
mosquitto_sub -t "1999-Connect"
If message ="1" sudo bash update.sh
else
restart script.
```

Comment: And write the code that I am asking how to write? I will try. Thank you for the tip. OP is edited.

Comment: Would it be better to put the MQTT message into a variable, then the shell can work from a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that my variable concept was close, but I guess it is easier to write to a file than a variable.

Write incoming command to a file called task:

```
mosquitto_sub -h SERVER -t '/TOPIC/' >> task
```

then read the file, and execute the last command with the following script:

```
NUMOFLINES=$(wc -l < task)

while :
do    
        NEWLINE=$(wc -l < task)

        if [ "$NEWLINE" -gt "$NUMOFLINES" ]
        then
                NUMOFLINES=$(wc -l < task)
                LASTCOMMAND=$(tail -n 1 task)
                eval ./$LASTCOMMAND
        fi    
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -u 10 m
do
  case "$m" in
    1)
      echo "Option 1 received"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Message: $m"
      ;;
    esac
done 10< <(mosquitto_sub -h localhost -t 'StarCommand')
```

The "10" is related to the file descriptor number 10, so you can always use the descriptor 2 and 3 (stdout and stderr).